# C# how can I extract photos from a zip file faster and more efficiently without extracting them using ZipArchive

Tags: c#, xamarin, asynchronous, async-await, zip

I have a xamarin app that reads photos without extracting them into a zip file.

When I click very quickly on the page where the photos should be displayed. Sometimes half doesn't show because the app hasn't been able to read them all yet.

Navigating after that page goes like this

```
    public async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Content tappedStep = (Content)MyListView.SelectedItem;
        int stepIndex = tappedStep.contentid;
        string nextTitle = _protocol.name;
        using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading", null, null, true, MaskType.Black))
        {
            loading = true;
            if (loading)
            {
                Title = nextTitle;
            }
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new StepView(_protocol, Title, tappedStep.chaptertitle, stepIndex));
        }

        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

So if I want to navigate too quickly after the stepview, the photos are often not all there.

This is the code I use to read the photos in the zip file.

```
    private string PathToZip()
    {
        string folderName = $"protocol-{_protocol.id}-{_protocol.versionnr}.zip";
        string extractPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        string zipPath = $"{$"{extractPath}"}/{$"{folderName}"}";
        return zipPath;
    }

    private async Task GetImage()
    {
        try
        {
            PathToZip();
            int currentIndex = GetCurrentIndex();
            Content content = _protocol.contents[currentIndex];
            string imageName = $"{content.contentid}.jpg";
            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(PathToZip()))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < archive.Entries.Count; i++)
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry pictureEntry = archive.Entries[i];
                    if (pictureEntry.Name == imageName)
                    {
                        //for reading the image
                        byte[] buffer;
                        long length = pictureEntry.Length;
                        buffer = new byte[length];
                        pictureEntry.Open().Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
                        myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(buffer));
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

How can I make this more efficient so that if the app hasn't loaded everything yet, when I want to navigate to the next page, the app then waits for each page to be read?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have an async method without using await?

Comment: What should i change then? @JonasH

Comment: i await getimage where i need to call them if that is what you mean

Comment: why don't you just extract all of the images ahead of time?  Or display an ActivityIndicator while you're waiting to extract the image?

Comment: using `async` does not automagically make your method asynchronous. It only tells the compiler to transform the method so it *can* be paused/resumed while it waits for something, Usually some IO-operation. If you are not awaiting something inside the method it will behave just as a non-async method. So using async in that way will just cause confusion.

Comment: What should i change code wise can you give a example maybe? @JonasH

Comment: Just change `async Task` to `void`.